# JasperReports Inserts Indention For Every New Page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a text field and I specified left indent 40px for the text. And if this text is too long *JasperReports* continues from the new page. Thats okay no prob until here.

But In new page *JasperReports* inserts a left indent for **every new page**.

But I don't want to be placed left indent property in new page. I need left indent only once at first page. Not at second or third. So, Are there any way to tell this to *JasperReports*?  Same a my question, there is one in *JasperReports* community. But not answered. If you could take a look an image, you could easily understand problem.

[image]

Comment: It is a good question. Did you check the source code?

Comment: Need to test the only solution that I can come up with for now is instead of left indent use `"    " + $F{fieldName}`

Comment: I think this is a fair bug and it would be great if you could log it on our JR Lib project trackers.